# xcode - Design / Redesign MailController / MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Is it possible to Redesign the MFMailComposeViewController?

How?

The App Dropbox can do it.
Picture: http://jonathangurebo.tumblr.com/post/40436277822

Can I change the "MessageUI.framework"?

Comment: What different? That's the same `MFMailComposeViewController` I've seen in every app, including my own.

Comment: You might be aiming at the wrong target. They have most likely customised the appearance of the view without changing the framework itself. Try session 216 (Advanced Appearance Customization on iOS) from WWDC 2012 which shows how this can be done: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=216

Comment: sorry i mean the Navigation Bar on The mailController. in the video i can se that they can change a normal Navigation Bar with the code: [bar setBackgroundImage:img]; (something like that) but how to change the navigation bar on the MailController?

Comment: You are not talking about the redesign of the `MFMailComposeViewController`, you are simply talking about using the `UIAppearance` methods to set an app level color scheme. That's all this is.

Comment: Ok, but how can i change all Navigation Bars(included the mail bar)? How can i get my current nav bar to view in mail controller?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your request regarding customizing the appearance of ALL navigation bars in the app, use this in your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: in your app delegate:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setAlpha:1]; 
//change background image and tint color for navigation buttons

        // Set the text appearance for navbar
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:2 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]; //change vertical appearance of navigation bar title
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
          [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
          [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
          [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(1, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
          [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:22], UITextAttributeFont,
          nil]]; //set custom font info
```